# Powershell using Invoke-Command and Get-Childitem not delivering content

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell 4.0 on a remote computer (*rem_comp*) to access another one (*loc_comp*; Powershell 2.0 installed here) in order to get the number of files listed without folders:

```
$var1 = 'H:\scripts'
Invoke-Command -Computername loc_comp -scriptblock {(Get-Childitem $var1 -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).count}
```

However when using `$var1` inside -scriptblock, it does not deliver anything (neither any error message).

When using

```
$var1 = 'H:\scripts'
Invoke-Command -Computername loc_comp -scriptblock {(Get-Childitem $ -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).count}
```

it works!

Note: Changing `var1` from ' to " does not help.

Running the command without `Invoke-Command` locally faces the same problem.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using Invoke-command and a script-block , the scriptblock cannot access your params from the outer scope (scoping rules).

You can however, define the params and pass them along with the -Argumentlist

Example:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName "localhost" {param($Param1=$False, $Param2=$False) Write-host "$param1 $param2" } -ArgumentList $False,$True
```

The following should work for your example:

```
Invoke-Command -Computername loc_comp -scriptblock {param($var1)(Get-Childitem $var1 -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).count} -ArgumentList $var1
```

Comment: Thanks. However can you please be more specific in regards to the command I have to use instead in detail?

Comment: Updated answer with example for your case now.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [CmdrTchort's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35653745/45375):

**PS v3** introduced the special **`using:` scope**, which allows **direct use of local variables in script blocks sent to remote machines** (e.g., `$using:var1`).
<sup>This should work for you, because the machine you're running `Invoke-Command` *on* has v4.</sup>

```
$var1 = 'H:\scripts'
Invoke-Command -Computername loc_comp -scriptblock `
  { (Get-Childitem $using:var1 -recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}).count }
```

Note that `using:` only works when `Invoke-Command` actually targets a *remote* machine.